# Eclipse is not recognizing my android phone

Tags: android

I am using eclipse on windows
i want to run application on my samsung android phone
but eclipse is not recognizing my device
pease somebody help me

Answer (score 2):

Go tthrough this link you will find the answer http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

This page describes how to set up your development environment and Android-powered device for testing and debugging on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install the Google USB drivers and another other drivers that might be needed for Windows to recognise the phone.

Start here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

you should use proper drivers for windows and also try to install samsung kies.
http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

Answer (score 0):

Try this way this is Works For Me.

In your Samsung device.

Go To `Setting->Applications->Development->`

To Download driver software (Eclipse) for Samsung Device Automatically you should connect to windows pc & `not check USB debugging option`.

Once the All Drivers are downloaded after that all samsung devices will connect with eclipse & when you should do debug any application `check USB debugging option`.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, Windows was unable to update the driver software for my Android phone in the Device Manager.

Finally found this website http://www.driverscape.com/download/android-adapter-adb-interface which has the software for all kinds of Windows OS.

This time Eclipse recognized my device.